# PHP - Getting Multiple Radio Buttons Values from From Submission

Tags: php

I am a newbie in PHP. I have a form like below:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
    <input id="radio-ge-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-ge" type="radio" value="1" checked>
    <label for="radio-ge-1" class="radio-custom-label tooltips">1 <span>Impossible to get marks</span></label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input id="radio-ge-2" class="radio-custom" name="radio-ge" value="2" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-ge-2" class="radio-custom-label tooltips">2 <span>You have to work hard to get marks</span></label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input id="radio-ge-3" class="radio-custom" name="radio-ge" value="3" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-ge-3" class="radio-custom-label tooltips">3 <span>The usual, just like any other class</span></label>
</div>


<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
    <input id="radio-sl-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-sl" value="1" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="radio-sl-1" class="radio-custom-label tooltips">1 <span>Unbearable pressure</span></label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input id="radio-sl-2" class="radio-custom" name="radio-sl" value="2" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-sl-2" class="radio-custom-label tooltips">2 <span>High pressure, But doable</span></label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input id="radio-sl-3" class="radio-custom" name="radio-sl" value="3" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-sl-3" class="radio-custom-label tooltips">3 <span>Fair, just like any other class</span></label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to save both radio buttons value in PHP by using the code:

```
$g_Easiness = $_POST['radio-ge'];
$s_Load = $_POST['radio-sl'];
```

But in this case, I'me only getting the first button's value. Second button's value = on.

I have spend more than two hours to figure it out. But cannot resolve it. Can anyone please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: name them `radio-sl[]` instead of `radio-sl`

Comment: @Farkie why exactly? That doesn't solve anything. Usually it sends on when you have input=checkbox. Is there any javascript involved before sending the form?

Comment: It's a huge form and I've some checkboxes after 5 radio buttons. A little script for restricting the maximum # of options also added.

Comment: What is the name of those checkboxes @musafir

Comment: Yes, I need some int values fro the checked options.

Comment: `<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div>
            <input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="tags[]" value="Tough Grader" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom-label">Tough Grader</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div>
            <input id="checkbox-2" class="checkbox-custom" name="tags[]" value="Dull Classes" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-2" class="checkbox-custom-label">Dull Classes</label>
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST)` when you send the form?

Comment: Don't know about `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: How did you get those value @BrijalSavaliya

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/musafirshahid/temp/blob/master/index.php @BrijalSavaliya

Comment: https://github.com/musafirshahid/temp/blob/master/ratings.php

Comment: This should be a chat, not a comments now. @Daan because it will send it as an array, not as a single element, essentially overwriting each other as they all have the same name.

Comment: I'm getting value 1 for the first one, but rest of all are giving me the value on.

Comment: When i submit code it will give array like 
Array
(
    [instuctor-name] => 
    [designation] => 
    [university] => 
    [description] => 
    [course-id] => 
    [radio-ge] => 1
    [radio-sl] => 1
    [radio-ea] => 1
    [radio-n] => 1
    [radio-feel] => happy
    [radio-nns] => absolutely
    [radio-at] => on
    [radio-tb] => on
    [grade] => 
)

Comment: How did you get this array. I just need that piece of code. Actually, I'm very new in PHP. So, I can't explain it to you properly may be. I need all the form fields value to save them in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code for radio buttons
if input type="radio" then it should give value="" otherwise in value it will show "on"
e.g.

```
<input id="radio-must" class="radio-custom" name="radio-nns" value="absolutely" type="radio" checked>

output = [radio-nns] => on
```

instead put  ( you can see  value="1")

```
<input id="radio-must" class="radio-custom" name="radio-nns" value="absolutely" type="radio" checked value="1">

output =  [radio-nns] =>1
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother. Yes, I will change them to some INT value. It will be very helpful if you tell how did you retrieve this array: `Array ( [instuctor-name] => [designation] => [university] => [description] => [course-id] => [radio-ge] => 1 [radio-sl] => 1 [radio-ea] => 1 [radio-n] => 1 [radio-feel] => happy [radio-nns] => absolutely [radio-at] => on [radio-tb] => on [grade] => )`

Comment: if you want to print something you can just put code like (e.g. put code in rating.php starting )

print "<pre>"; // for print in proper format
print_r($_POST); //for print post array
die; // for stop execution of code